# The torus cannot cover $\Bbb S^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I know that $S^2$ cannot cover the torus $\Bbb T^2 \cong \Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1$ because $S^2 \not \cong \Bbb R^2$ and both are universal coverings of $\Bbb T^2$

Conversely, is there a covering $p:\Bbb T^2 \to \Bbb S^2$?

Such a covering would induce a trivial injective morphism $p_*:\pi_1(\Bbb T^2) \to \pi_1(\Bbb S^2)$, therefore all loops in  $\Bbb T^2$ would be nullhomotopic, but $\Bbb T^2$ is not simply connected.

Is it a correct argument?

Thank you for you help and comments.

Comment: It is correct. And more generally, the unique covering of a simply connected space is itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I fully follow your argument for why $S^2$ cannot cover $T^2$. You mean to say that since $S^2$ is simply connected, it would be a universal cover of $T^2$ if there were a covering map $\rho:S^2\to T^2$, but you know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a universal cover of $T^2$, that universal covers are homeomorphic, and $S^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

For the converse, a covering map $\rho:T^2\to S^2$ would *not* induce an injective homomorphism $\pi_1(T^2)\to\pi_1(S^2)$. That's the end of it; that's why it can't happen. There are no injective group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}^2 \to 0$. (Any covering map induces an injective map on fundamental groups by uniqueness of path lifting.)

Comment: exactly @csprun for the first part, and yes for the second part!